# How can I connect to Wi-Fi with a Windows Mobile through WPS?

Tags: wifi, windows-mobile

Is it possible to connect to a wifi network using WPS Pin and a Windows Mobile (PocketPC) phone?

Note: I know windows mobile is old but I really need to do that and Windows mobile is previous version of Windows phone.

Comment: It's likely that the device and software pre-date WPS and don't support it.

Comment: @NeilTurner So I can't write an application for that too? :(

Comment: No, wifi is handled by the OS + drivers.